# Create as many files as the number of items from two lists with the same number of items in Python

Tags: python

Consider the file `testbam.txt`:

```
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
```

and the file `testbai.txt`:

```
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
```

They always have in common the same length and I created a function to find it:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i,l in enumerate(f):
            pass
        return i+1

n = file_len('/groups/cgsd/alexandre/python_code/src/testbai.txt')
print(n)
3
```

Then I created two lists by opening the files and doing some manipulation:

```
content = []
with open('/groups/cgsd/alexandre/python_code/src/testbam.txt') as bams:
    for line in bams:
        content.append(line.strip().split())

print(content)

content2 = []
with open('/groups/cgsd/alexandre/python_code/src/testbai.txt') as bais:
    for line in bais:
        content2.append(line.strip().split())

print(content2)
```

Now I have a `json` type file called `mutec.json` that I would like to replace certain parts with the items of the lists:

```
{
    "Mutect2.gatk_docker": "broadinstitute/gatk:4.1.4.1",
    "Mutect2.intervals": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/interval_list/Basic_Core_xGen_MSI_TERT_HPV_EBV_hg38.interval_list",
    "Mutect2.scatter_count": 30,
    "Mutect2.m2_extra_args": "--downsampling-stride 20 --max-reads-per-alignment-start 6 --max-suspicious-reads-per-alignment-start 6",
    "Mutect2.filter_funcotations": true,
    "Mutect2.funco_reference_version": "hg38",
    "Mutect2.run_funcotator": true,
    "Mutect2.make_bamout": true,
    "Mutect2.funco_data_sources_tar_gz": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/mutect2/inputs/funcotator_dataSources.v1.6.20190124s.tar.gz",
    "Mutect2.funco_transcript_selection_list": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/mutect2/inputs/transcriptList.exact_uniprot_matches.AKT1_CRLF2_FGFR1.txt",
  
    "Mutect2.ref_fasta": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ref_Homo38_HPV/Homo_sapiens_assembly38_chrHPV.fasta",
    "Mutect2.ref_fai": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ref_Homo38_HPV/Homo_sapiens_assembly38_chrHPV.fasta.fai",
    "Mutect2.ref_dict": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ref_Homo38_HPV/Homo_sapiens_assembly38_chrHPV.dict",
    
    "Mutect2.tumor_reads": "<<<N_item_of_list_content>>>",
    "Mutect2.tumor_reads_index": "<<<N_item_of_list_content2>>>",
  }
```

Please note that this section:

```
   "Mutect2.tumor_reads": "<<<N_item_of_list_content>>>",
   "Mutect2.tumor_reads_index": "<<<N_item_of_list_content2>>>",
```

`<<<N_item_of_list_content>>>` and `<<<N_item_of_list_content2>>>` should be replaced by their respective items of the list and I would like to finally write the result of every modification into a new file.

The final result would be 3 files: `mutect1.json` with first item from `testbam.txt` and first item from `testbai.txt` , `mutect2.json` with second item from `testbam.txt` and second item from `testbai.txt` and third file with the same reasoning applied.

Please note that the notation I wrote `<<<N_item_of_list_content>>>` and `<<<N_item_of_list_content2>>>` isn't necesserarily hard-coded into the file, I wrote myself just to make clear what I would like to replace.

Comment: Your question is not focused!! Too many questions in one. You can just ask one thing where you got a problem/error.

Comment: why not ? I did my best to provide all details

Comment: take a look at your first code above. it opened up a for loop and all it did was `pass`. What is that?

Comment: then let me know what I should delete form the question please

Comment: The last sentence make the question unclear. If you do not want to replace a specific string, how will you find what is to replace?

Comment: it `returns i+1`

Comment: I thought about some `{}.format` code , the string can be whatever string and in the loop the string will change anyway at every iteration

Comment: @AvenDesta: the function is not really Pythonic, but it returns the expected result...

Comment: @alex:: I can help you to find something and replace it, but I need to know what is to replace, and how to identify it...

Comment: @SergeBallesta ok take `/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bam` and `/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bai`  the first line of both files for example. Then what I need is two more files with the other items

Comment: I thought rather about a general case which the variable would expand to `list[index]` at that specific location, no matter what is written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and even if it is unrelated to the question, some of your code is not really Pythonic:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i,l in enumerate(f):
            pass
        return i+1
```

You use a for loop over `enumerate` when you should simply do:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return len(f)
```

because f is an iterator over the lines of the file

Now to your question. You want to replace some elements in a file with data found in two other files.

In your initial question, the strings were enclosed in triple angle brackets.

I would have used:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'<<<.*?>>>')        # how to identify what is to replace

with open('.../testbam.txt') as bams, open('.../testbai.txt') as bais, \
     open('.../mutect.json') as src:
    for i, reps in enumerate(zip(bams, bais), 1): # gets a pair of replacement strings at each step
        src.seek(0)                  # rewind src file
        with open(f'mutect{i}', 'w') as fdout:  # open the output files
            rep_index = 0            # will first use rep string from first file
            for line in src:
                if rx.search(line):  # if the string to replace there?
                    line = rx.sub(reps[rep_index], line)
                    rep_index = 1 - rep_index    # next time will use the other string
                fdout.write(line)
```

In comments, you proposed to change the first line of each file with the others. The code could become:

```
with open('.../testbam.txt') as bams, open('.../testbai.txt') as bais, \
     open('.../mutect.json') as src:
    it = iter(zip(bams, bais))
    to_find = next(it)          # we will have to find that
    for i, reps in enumerate(it, 2): # gets a pair of replacement strings at each step
        src.seek(0)                  # rewind src file
        with open(f'mutect{i}', 'w') as fdout:  # open the output files
            for line in src:
                line = line.replace(to_find[0], reps[0])    # just try to replace
                line = line.replace(to_find[1], reps[1])
                fdout.write(line)
```